# Adaptar web a móvil

Tags: bootstrap, web, responsive

Me gustaría saber cómo puedo adaptar esta parte del código (imagen) al tamaño de móvil, ya que en web se ve perfecto pero en móvil se corta la imagen de abajo y se pega con la de arriba

```
<div class="slider-btn mt-30">
</div>
<div class="col-lg-7"></div>
<img src="img/bg-img/kindpng_3387600.png" alt="">
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-5">
   <div class="welcome-thumb home-3" style="margin-top: 110px">
      <img src="img/bg-img/smartmockups_kconkpot.png" alt="">
   </div>
</div>
```

Con el grid se solucionó que no se monten ambas imágenes, pero la segunda se sigue cortando.
class="img-fluid" tampoco lo solventa, en el boostrap lo tengo así:
`img-fluid{max-width:100%;height:auto}`

Añado style:

```
@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 991px) {
.welcome-area.home-3 {
        height: 800px;
    }

.welcome-thumb.home-3 {
        width: 300px;
        margin: auto;
```

Comment: El [grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/grid/) te lo soluciona, ahora tienes `col-lg-7` eso significa que en pantallas grandes ocupará 7 de las 12 columnas, si quieres que funcione en movil puedes usar `xs` o `sm`

Comment: A las imagenes solo ponle la class="img-fluid" con boostrap y ya con eso debería quedar te dejo el link por si quieres mas información https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/content/images/